# How to test a custom slice of an application with custom application class in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing

I am working on a Spring Shell application where the testing is a bit quirky. Testing of a Spring Shell application requires its own `@ShellTest` [annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/reference/testing/basics.html). If the test class is annotated by `@SpringBootTest` the application just [waits](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/issues/721#issuecomment-1528796888) and nothing happens.

What I need is separate out the business logic from the shell code and test it in isolation. I can use `@SpringBootTest` to wire up all the components I need and test the business logic. But, I don't know how.

Can this be solved by test configuration? Or does it require a separate Application class? To where should I put this custom application class? How can I specify in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation that the test should use a certain class. I searched for this, but all the blogs are about how to test MVC and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it in my project with SpringShell is I basically only started ApplicationContext with that one Bean that I needed - you can easisly do that by defining `classes` in `@SpringBootTest` annotation  - so say I have the following class that I want to test:

```java
@Component
@Command(group = "Main Commands")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InstallCommand 

  // doesn't matter if interactive or not
  @Command(command = "install", interactionMode = INTERACTIVE) 
    public String installApp(@Option(longNames = "environment", shortNames = 'e') String environment) {
        // some logic
        installationService.install(environment);
        return "installed";
    }
}
```

then I just do the following test - simple version:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = InstallCommand.class)
class InstallCommandTest {

    @Autowired
    InstallCommand installCommand;

    @MockBean
    InstallationService installationService;

    @Test
    void testInstall_demo() {
        // GIVEN that I have the following environment
        String environment = "environment";
        
        // WHEN I call installApp with that parameter
        String installResult = this.installCommand.installApp(environment);

        // THEN installResult is the correct
        assertEquals("installed", installResult);

        // AND installationService was called with the correct parameter
        Mockito.verify(installationService, times(1)).install(environment);
    }
}
```